# 403 response with HttpClient but not with browser

Tags: httpclient

I’m having a problem with the HttpClient library in java.

The target web site is on SSL (https://www.betcris.com), and I can load the index page from that site just fine .

However, the different pages showing odds for the different sports returns a 403 response code with HttpClient, but loading the same pages in a browser works just fine.

Here is such a page : https://www.betcris.com/en/live-lines/soccer.

I started troubleshooting this page with the information gathered by HttpFox (a Firefox add-on that resembles LiveHttpHeaders), making sure I had all the correct request headers and cookies, but I couldn’t get it to load using HttpClient.  I also determined that cookies have nothing to do with the problem, as I can remove all cookies for that web site within my browser, and then hit the page directly and it will load.

I confirmed that there’s something special going on with these pages by using the online tool at http://www.therightapi.com/test.  This tool allows you to input the url of a page along with any Request header you want, and shows you the response you get from the target web site.  Using that tool, I can load https://www.google.com just fine, but I get the same 403 error when trying to load https://www.betcris.com/en/live-lines/soccer.

Here's my setup at therightapi :

[image]

And the response :

[image]

Does anyone know what’s going on here ?

Thanks.

EDIT : I've created a test project, here's the java code, followed by the maven dependency you should have in your pom :

```
package com.yourpackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class TestHttpClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://www.betcris.com/en/live-lines/soccer";

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        // add request header
        request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            System.out.println("Response Code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this problem (avoiding 403) by setting up ***User-Agent*** property while making a request as like follow:

- If you use **HttpClient**

  ```
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL_HERE);
  httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) 
      AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
  ```
- If you use **HttpURLConnection**

  ```
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();    
  connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) 
      AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to consume HTTPS Urls:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;

...

    SSLContext sslContext =
            new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, (certificate, authType) -> true).build();

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext)
                                                     .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build()) {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("YOUR_HTTPS_URL");
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent",
                          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        logger.info("Response: " + response);

    }
```

pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the web server does not use a proxy to communicate with APIs.

I just disbaled the **defaultproxy** under **system.net** in **web.config**.

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" />
   </system.net>
```

Answer (score -1):

`403 Forbidden` is used to signal an authentication requirement. In fact, the full 403 response should tell you exactly that. Luckily, [HttpClient can do authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html).

Comment: I understand that.  What I don't understand is how my browser, with all cookies and cache cleared, can access that web page WITHOUT any authentication ?

Comment: @user1646686: Authentication does not depend on cookies or caches.

Comment: can you please elaborate on that, as my understanding of authentication using HTTP is that a user will provide a username and password to a server, the server will create a session once that username and password is verified, and then return a cookie to the caller, and that cookie will be returned from that point on in future calls to that server, enabling the server to match the information in the cookie to the session.  I fail to see what authentication is taking place if I access the url in question without providing any credentials ?

Comment: @user1646686: There is no reason why the server must create a session. The cookie is only used to find back the session. The actual authentication is carried in the `Authentication: ` HTTP header, not the `Cookie: ` header. A server is free to say "Well, I see that you have the right session cookie, so I'm not going to insist on the Authentication header", but this would be insecure (could lead lead to session stealing). Of course, if security is really important you'd use HTTPS instead.

Comment: Ok, then can you see that 'Authentication:' header when you access the url in question : https://www.betcris.com/en/live-lines/soccer ?  I can't see it in HttpFox, nor can I see it in Chrome's developer tools pane...